# Regarding session statingin asp.net

Tags: asp.net

if anyhow my session have ended then how can i start the session again in the code.

Comment: Why do you want to open it again? You can't do that, but depending on what you're trying to achieve there may be other solutions, perhaps as simple as increasing the session timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. When the session is gone either from the browser or the server, it can't be reopened, you have to start a new session.

Reopening a session that was closed in the browser would be a potential security risk. Reopening a session that was closed from the server isn't possible as the data simply doesn't exist any more.

Every request is done in the scope of a session (unless you specifically make a session-less request), so if the session is closed for any reason, a new one is automatically created at the next request.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, if you wanted a session to stay alive, you had to write your app in such a way that requests were continually made to the server within the session timeout. This could be using a ajax request or a iframe postback on a javascript timer. I never really liked those methods, but for some apps they made sense.

Here is a simple example of a ajax-based session-refresh:
http://naspinski.net/post/Automatically-refresh-your-users-Session-behind-the-scenes-using-jQuery-and-AspNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**You can't** do that, but you can use `Session.RemoveAll()`.